# Nvidia GTX 960 Lower FPS If Overclocked

Tags: performance, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, overclocking

I am trying to over-clock my EVGA NVIDIA Geforce GTX 960. I am using EVGA precision X to do so. Whenever I try changing the base clock even a little I instantly to 1/4 of the original performance. I have tried turning up the voltage and still no change. If I try to over-clock then revert the settings back to normal I still get a lowered performance its only on reboot that it restores the performance. The temperature doesn't increase if I turn up the base clock or the voltage, its as if when I try to adjust it all it does is reduce the performance.

Please Help!

Comment: You might just have a non-overclockable card. Luck-of-the-draw

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It is an overlockable card and it is currently self overclocking (p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarke, 
I'm afraid I don't have experience using Precision X to overclock video cards, but I may be able to help you nonetheless.  I recommend you go into your BIOS and start with the base figures for your video card.  That means turn off any automatic overclocking or adjustments that might have already been made.  Then use a more popular tool, such as MSI's Afterburner, to achieve the clock speeds you want.  You'll find much more support with Afterburner as well.  Happy FPS Hunting!